# Windows 8 Chinese Input: Trackpad and Stylus

Tags: input-methods

When using a laptop touchpad to input Chinese via handwriting on Windows 8, I either have to double tap or press down in order to write. On a MacBook, I just write without needing an initial double tap or pressing down while writing. Is there a way to do the same in Windows 8? I read through some of Pinyin Joes pieces on Windows 8, he doesn't seem to have any info on this.

Also, I tried using an iPad/iPhone stylus on a Windows 8 laptop touchscreen, it doesn't seem to be as receptive as on iOS devices. For example, if I write 我, it will miss every other or every third stroke. Is this a function of the touchscreen as it is a budget laptop or the stylus? Are styluses for Windows 8 different than those for Apple?

Comment: Try this website : http://cndic.naver.com/ A Korean Chinese-Korean online dictionary where you're allowed to input Chinese character by handwriting.

Comment: Steve, just thinking, do you have any stores there (I'm not from US) like a Best Buy or something like that where they have a bunch of laptops already set up that you could request to test out a few different styluses?

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 Good idea. I was planning on doing this, just haven't had time yet. Just hoping someone out there could save me the trip. Hopefully I can try today.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly two ways for you to input Chinese:

1) Use a Free PinYin inputter such as Sogou:http://pinyin.sogou.com/
[image]
2) After installing, you can do writing with TouchPad on your notepad：
[image]